# Where can I find the `enable_rest_service` parameter originally in the `conf/iotdb-common.properties` directory for Apache IoTDB Version 1.3?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have just upgraded Apache IoTDB to Version 1.3, but found that the `enable_rest_service` configuration parameter originally in the `conf/iotdb-common.properties` file no longer exists. Are there any changes in the location and settings of this configuration? I compiled the coding and add this parameter myself, and found that it seems can be normally used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `enable_rest_service` parameter has already been changed to `iotdb-datanode.properties` directory in Apache IoTDB. You can also continue to use your compile version under `conf/iotdb-common.properties` file.